# Re-use An Import-Mapping of a CSV into SQL Azure DB using SSMS

Tags: csv, azure, import, ssms, ssis

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503430/import-csv-into-sql-azure-database-using-ssms/35876305#35876305 one solution was to save the import dtsx so as to reuse.  However, I cannot find how to "reuse" the session in SSMS.

I've looked at:

- setting up a Data Factory so I can get an SSIS - which seems like more cost to run something that I'm usually manually doing anyway (but not wanting to respecify the parameters each time).
- using BCP, but this requires an SSIS somewhere - which leaves me wondering how do I get such if all I have is AZURE (back to Data Factory)
- DTEXEC and DTEXECUI - however, I think that only works with SQL Server which I don't want to install
- Visual Studio - perhaps so that I can use the Solution Explorer

When I've opted to save the session, hoping to write to the Azure SSIS via SSMS (after I've set up a Data Factory) I've been unable to connect and therefore unable to save.

Where should I be looking to figure out how to save a CSV mapping (which works right manually) to repeat monthly if the only DB I use is AZURE and don't want to also create a local SQL SERVER DB?